# Can't use RapidApi with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rapidapi

I'm new with Retrofit and I'm trying to use Google Translate Api from RapidApi with Retrofit but i can't convert okhttp code snippet to retrofit

This is the sample code snippet for Post request working with OkHttp:

```
val client = OkHttpClient()

val mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
val body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "q=Hello%2C%20world!&target=es")
val request = Request.Builder()
    .url("https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2")
    .post(body)
    .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/gzip")
    .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com")
    .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", API_KEY)
    .build()

val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```

i want to make same request with Retrofit in android

This is my api interface:

```
interface TranslatorApi {

    @Headers(
        "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept-Encoding: application/gzip",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host: google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key: API_KEY
    )
    @POST("translate/v2")
    suspend fun translate(
        @Body q: String,
        @Query("target") target: String,
        @Query("source") source: String
    ): Response<GoogleTranslateObject>
}
```

Comment: not sure if you're using a free or private key, but usually it isn't a good idea to post it on the internet, hopefully it's just a demo one

Comment: It's just a demo, but i edit it anyway, Thanks

Comment: Please remove the following lines from your code and try again "X-RapidAPI-Host: google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com"

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
interface TranslationApi {

@Headers(
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept-Encoding: application/gzip",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key: $API_KEY",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host: google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com"
)
@POST("language/translate/v2")
@FormUrlEncoded
suspend fun translateText(
    @Field("q") query: String,
    @Field("target") targetLang: String = "tr",
    @Field("source") sourceLang: String = "en"
): Response<TranslationResponseDto>
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?